# What is the difference between a javascript package, node package, and react package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular

Are they all the same thing? Can a node program use react package, vice versa?

Comment: Almost any package from npm or yarn can used anywhere

Answer (score 5):

[JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_js.asp) (JS) is a programing language

There are many libraries and packages build for JS; one of these is React.

Further packages can be built using as dependencies a base package, for example, "react packages" are libraries built to extend functionalities from the [react](https://github.com/facebook/react) packages.

[NodeJs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_introduction.htm) is a platform or often refereed as a "runtime" for server-side applications. It uses the JS language in its syntax
"node packages" are JS libraries built to be run by NodeJs.